# SCALA - expression (for{}yield x) is of type Future[Future[..]] instead of expected Future[..]

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
val futureWithResult = for{files <- scanFiles(dir)
                            res <- procFiles(files)}yield res
```

res is of type `Future[...]`, why does this statement return `Future[Future[..]]`??
In my program I need futureWithResult to be `Future[...]`. Why is my yield code wrapping the type of res into another `Future[]`?

Comment: what are the return types of the `scanFiles` and `procFiles` methods?

Comment: scanFiles - Seq[String]
procFiles - Future[Seq[(String, Int)]]

[. . .] in my question stands for the type Seq[(String, Int)]

Comment: @DorianOlympia, with the given types `scanFiles: Seq[String]` and `procFiles: Future[Seq[(String, Int)]]` you cannot write a for comprehension because the `flatMap` of `scanFiles` expects a `GenTraversableOnce` value which the future value is not. Thus, your code should not compile.

Comment: @TillRohrmann scanFiles is of type Array[String], sorry my bad. The code compiles perfectly but it doesn't work. This snippetis part of a listing from the book Scala in Action, therefore everything should work - but it doesn't.

Comment: @DorianOlympia, also with the `scanFiles: Array[String]`, my Scala compiler, 2.11.7, complains. Again because a `Future` is not a `GenTraversableOnce`. Have you tried to compile the code? I assume that the book Scala in Action is wrong then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. The problem was indeed in wrong types (to be exact, with the type of res). It was `Future[Seq[(String, Int)]]` instead of `Seq[(String, Int)]` The problem was that I wrapped procFiles (which returns Future[. . .]) into another Future by mistake. Thank's guys for all the comments!

Comment: you can accept your own answer to prevent others from reaching this unnecessarily.